# Locust: Failed apis with count are not getting included in csv report

Tags: python, performance, locust

[image: locust conf file]

we are running the load test via this command:

**locust --config=./config/entity_publish_flows.conf**

But after completion of load test, **we see that failed apis are not getting listed in csv** although failures are getting logged in log file.
Actually there are total 11 apis, but as 3 apis are giving error, only 8 apis are getting included in csv_stats report

Locust version: 2.12.2

Please suggest if I am missing something.

[image: Report File]
[image: Log File]

Comment: It looks like you have custom code for your logging and your reporting to Locust. That means there may be something wrong in your code that's not reporting your failures to Locust. If you show some code instead of just the errors, we might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this, you have to write like this when doing any API call by using **catch_Reponse=True** and r**esponse.failure("any message")**:

```
def get(self, endpoint, headers, name=None):
    with self.client.get(endpoint, headers=headers, name=name, catch_response=True,
                     cookies=self.user.get_cookie()) as response:
         if response.status_code == 200:
            Logger.log_message('GET API Call Successful for endpoint: {}'.format(endpoint))
         else:
            response.failure("got wrong response")
            raise RescheduleTask()
```